# breakRoleInheritance and RemoveRole CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, roles

I need to breakRoleInheritance on the items of a SharePoint2013 list. 
I need to remove all the current roles and add only the Owner and the Current user.
How can I do it by client side?

Thanks, Nk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following example shows how to break role inheritance of a list item and give current user Contribute permissions to the item.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function breakSecurityInheritanceAddUser() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');

    var itemId = 4;
    //this.oListItem = oList.get_items().getById(itemId);
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);

    oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false, false);

    this.oUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);

    collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.contributor));

    oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(oUser, collRoleDefinitionBinding);  
    clientContext.load(oUser);
    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    alert('Role inheritance broken for item ' + 
        this.oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        ' and new role assignment for ' + 
        this.oUser.get_loginName());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

This example shows how to give group permissions on the list item:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function breakSecurityInheritanceAddUser() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');

    var itemId = 4;
    this.oListItem = oList.get_items().getById(itemId);

    oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false, false);

    this.oUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);

    collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.fullControl));

    var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    var group = groupCollection.getByName("Owner Group Name");

    oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(group, collRoleDefinitionBinding);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

**UPDATE**

`oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false, false);` will make sure that no roles are inherited from parent list. However, if you want to explicitly remove a role, then use following sample code:

```
oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(true);

this.oUser = clientContext.get_web().get_siteUsers().getByLoginName('DOMAIN\\alias');

oListItem.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(oUser).deleteObject();

var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);

collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.administrator));

oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(oUser, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
```

See this for more info:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! How can I remove an user or a role?

Comment: @NkSP, see my updated answer

Comment: Which permission do I need to perform this?
My users are in a Contribute group. Is there something like 'SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges'?

Comment: I think it should be done by a user having admin rights.

Comment: What if I am trying to do this in provider hosted app. What permission should be given to app for this?

Comment: May be useful to someone. The current user who runs the code need to have full control of the item.