# How can we achieve assigning permission set to a list different from permission set of its parent site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

How can we achieve assigning  permission set to a list different from permission set of its parent site in SP 2013? Can it be done both on SharePoint online and on-premise? How? I want the CSOM/JSOM/SSOM solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can by **Breaking Role Assignment Inheritance** From **UI** / **CSOM** **JSOM** / **SSOM** / **REST API**

**From UI see Image Below :**

[image]

**By using SSOM :**

```
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strURL))
{        
   using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
   {
      SPList list = oWeb.Lists["ListName"];
      list.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
    }            
}
```

**By using CSOM :**

```
function breakSecurityInheritance() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    // provide the list name
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    oList.breakRoleInheritance(false, true);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("Updated");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**By using JSOM :**

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function breakSecurityInheritance() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    oList.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);

    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

        alert(this.oList.get_title() + ' role inheritance broken.');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**By using REST API :**

```
//Create the REST header



var headers = {  
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
}  

 //Create the REST end point URL  
var endPointUrl = "SiteUrl" + "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)";  

//Issue the REST Call  
var call = jQuery.ajax({  
      url: endPointUrl,  
      type: "POST",  
      headers: headers,  
      dataType: 'json',success: function (data) {  
           alert(‘Inheritance Broken Successfully !');  

        },  
        error: function (error) {  
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in SharePoint server object model, there is a method available for `SPWeb, SPList and SPListItem` called `BreakRoleInheritance`.

This object have two overload. Using this object you can break the permission grammatically.

Follow the url for more information about this method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.breakroleinheritance.aspx

**Edit**

In case if you are looking for CSOM based solution follow the below mentioned URL. [breakRoleInheritance and RemoveRole CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96320/breakroleinheritance-and-removerole-csom)

Comment: Can it be done through JSOM?

Comment: Yes, CSOM and JSOM have the same methods available. You port CSOM code JSOM code easily. Just make sure you use proper method name, for example in CSOM its `ctx.Web` while in JSOM its `ctx.get_web()`. In JSOM we dont have properties, we have methods for most of the properties. Also note that, the URL mentioned in answer as CSOM solution is actually having JSOM answer.